# Choose different Template at Run Time with InstantSearch.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, instantsearch.js

I want to be able to change the template depending on the value I got retrieved from the search. I thought of changing the variable content like this:

```
search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
     container: '#hits',
     hitsPerPage: 12,
     templates: {
        empty: noResultsTemplate,
        item: hitTemplate
     },
     transformData: function (hit) {
        if (hit.myVariable == true) {
          this.templates.item = otherTemplateVariable;
        }
        return hit;
     }
  })
);
```

But I get an error: `'Unable to get property 'templates' of undefined or null reference'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are referencing `this` and that points to the function `transformData` which do not have the templates attribute, try to extract your object to access it :

```
var data = {
     container: '#hits',
     hitsPerPage: 12,
     templates: {
        empty: noResultsTemplate,
        item: hitTemplate
     },
     transformData: function (hit) {
        if (hit.myVariable == true) {
          //access the templates attribute
          data.templates.item = otherTemplateVariable;
        }
        return hit;
     }
  };

search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.hits(data)
);
```

Comment: Tried but, does not use the new assigned template. Once is declared in 'templates' it will use that one :(. Corroborated this by removing 'item' from 'templates' list and added it to the else statement,and will no use neither.